# How do I defend against a robot suicide bomber?

Tags: near-future, tactics, terrorism

It is the near future. The Tesla Model X-2 has just been released as the world's first fully autonomous vehicle.

A international terrorist group steals one of the new models, holding its owner at gunpoint. The terrorists load the vehicle with 2,000 lb of high explosives, and force the owner to tell the car to drive to [350 West First Street, Los Angeles, CA](https://www.google.com/maps/place/United+States+Courthouse/@34.0537794,-118.2475026,449m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80c2c64e98dee4cb:0x6ab4febbf911c994!8m2!3d34.0537767!4d-118.2461568).

Moments after the car arrives, a cell phone call activates the bomb, resulting in the worst terrorist attack on US soil since 9/11.

**In the aftermath of this attack, what is the most effective way to keep Teslas from blowing up high value targets in the United States?**

#### Considerations

- Assume current US political climate. Surveillance of all US citizens is not permitted, for example.
- Account for other methods of setting off the bomb. If you can prevent cell phone signals from activating the bomb, the terrorists could use any other RF trigger. Jamming some or all RF signals in downtown LA is a non-starter. You need to prevent the car from getting to its destination carrying the bomb.

Comment: How is it any different from stopping suicide bombers?

Comment: @Mołot Well this is an autonomous car. It may be easier. It is certainly easier to find a car that will commit suicide than a person.

Comment: Easier to arrange such bombing, agreed. But about stopping it, I can't see any differences, really.

Comment: Can a Tesla haul 2000lbs?

Comment: I agree with @Mołot 's assessment.  There is no fundamental need to treat an autonomous suicide bomber any different from a suicide bomber driving a car, until you account for the number of suicide bombs that can be sent when you don't have to ask someone to commit suicide.  The instant that starts happening, the political climate will change overnight.

Comment: @CortAmmon I couldn't find a single suicide car bombing in the US on Wikipedia. If this starts happening at all, even once, it will be entirely new. That is why it needs to be treated differently.

Comment: No it does not. It has to be treated exactly the same, with important understanding that USA is not the whole world and there are countries where it already happened, where we can look at solutions implemented and political climate changes.

Comment: About political climate: people in USA would never agree to searches, limits etc when it comes to air travel. Never. And then: September, WTC... Asking to answer using political climate from before first attack makes no sense to me, because USA proved on example that once it happens, privacy and freedom can be taken away and nobody cares.

Comment: FWIW downvote is not from me. But I think I get where it came from.

Comment: Terrorists who pick what will likely be the most expensive autonomous vehicle every - it's a Tesla after all - these guys must be making a bomb. :-)

Comment: Why the emphasis on suicide? Does the name Timothy McVeigh come to mind? 168 dead. Made-in-USA terrorism. No need for international terrorists. America does quite well creating its own. No self-driving cars or hijacked vehicles necessary. Park-and-blow is not new.

Comment: @kingledion Timothy McVeigh.

Comment: It's a machine, so it's not committing suicide.  The use of the term is wrong.  It's more like a piloted drone - set the autopilot to navigate to X and wait there.  A suicide requires a human to willingly end their own life in the process of setting off the bomb.

Comment: *Assume current US political climate. Surveillance of all US citizens is not permitted*  This is just such a naive statement that it beggars belief.  What precisely do you think the e.g. FBI do all day ?  Wait for alarms to go of ?  Of course they use surveillance and lots of it - it's a necessity (they abuse this sometimes, but that's another story).

Comment: I found a suicide truck bomb in the US on Wikipedia quite quickly : see [Bath School Disaster 1927](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bath_School_disaster#Truck_explosion).  I'd honestly be surprised if there were not more.

Comment: Call Marvin the paranoid android.

Comment: @StephenG I found that one too. Who do you know that remembers that? No one remembers that. Like the tree that falls in the forest when no one is around, it didn't even happen.

Comment: @Mołot Comparison to air travel is trivial. Air travel is expected to take hours, and there are 2.5 million [airline passengers](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/by_the_numbers/) per day. There are 4.7 million car trips just in [ LA](http://www.laalmanac.com/employment/em22.php) every day; scale that up to the 85 million people in the US' 10 biggest metros and you have 38 million commuters. The magnitude of the problem is completely different; you can't search every car.

Answer (score 6):

### The Threat Model

Let's start by modelling our problem.

The scenario you've posited of a self driving car being used as a bomb, as has been mentioned, is quite similar to an ordinary kamikaze car bomb attack. Compared to a kamikaze car bomb attack, the smart-car bomb attack benefits from not requiring the death of its 'pilot'. However, it's also limited by the fact that a smart-car will drive to an appropriate parking space safely, and at a safe speed.

We can expect that this system would be difficult to override; a drunk/reckless driver attempting to override the self-driving controls and smashing into a storefront would pretty clearly be part of ordinary safety concerns. Thus, we can say that a would-be terrorist would have a hard time configuring a smart-car to, say, ram a building's entrance. They would have to settle for a parking space or remotely triggering somewhere along the route to a parking space.

Along the lines of the parked-car constraint, another threat scenario we can point to in the real world is that of a more conventional car bomb. There's plenty of examples of this kind of attack before the era of suicide bombings - the IRA, the first World Trade Centre attack, the list goes on. In this case, the attacker drives the weapon into some ordinary parking area then leaves the scene. Later, the bomb explodes (to some varying effect). Like a smart-car attack, an ordinary car bomb doesn't directly expose the attacker, and is constrained to ordinary travel routes. Unlike a smart-car attack, the attacker does not necessarily have to enter the vicinity of the attack, and the weapon could be triggered automatically (eg. when the car recognises that it has successfully parked) - removing any opportunity to identify the car as suspicious before it explodes.

Combining these two factors, we can model this problem in known terms: An attacker blackmails a car-owner (henceforth, the driver) into visiting a target location. Unbeknownst to the driver, the attacker has previously loaded the car with remote-controlled explosives and hidden cameras, which the attacker monitors from a hidden location. At an opportune moment, the attacker detonates the explosives.

Based on this threat model, we can come up with a few lines of defence that should effectively mitigate this type of attack:

### Spot the Explosives

It's no mistake that in the developed world we haven't seen any suicide bombing attacks for quite some time. Even in countries like Indonesia (that aren't generally in the view of the western world), the only suicide attack had very limited impact and was effectively halted by the police. In fact, the main impact was some young ladies developing a crush on a particularly dashing looking young officer. Security agencies around the world are *extremely* cognisant of the risk of explosives, and monitor anything that could potentially be used for explosives production closely, from fertiliser to civil explosives.

So the first line of defence is to spot the attacker before they're ready to attack. If they can't get explosives, then what they have is a car. A car that will safely park itself in front of a government building and achieve a parking fine. Meanwhile they can be arrested or tapped for information or even subjected to a sting operation.

It's unlikely, but possible that someone slips through the gaps - but this defence will likely make any explosives that *do* get through a lot weaker.

### Halt the Car

The car would likely have either an unwilling driver or no driver at all in this threat model. (The attacker sacrificing themselves we'll call out of scope, since at that point it's an ordinary suicide attack). Either would render a smart-car suspicious to passers-by and likely prompt police intervention.

Since a smart-car is self-driving, it's trivial to include electronics to make it smart-*stopping*. Using such remote lockout features would allow a smart car bomb detected in the process of driving to its destination to be easily halted at a safe distance and any victims rescued. In the worst case, the bomb gets triggered early, to reduced effect compared to the intended target.

This defence line is less effective in the case of an ordinarily-driverless car, like an automated delivery van.

### Protect Vulnerable Areas

Not all targets are high value, and not all high value targets are vulnerable to this attack. We can expect that our attackers would be aiming to target places where lots of people congregate, to maximise damage. However, we can also rule out some places; for example, a major sports stadium is unlikely to be vulnerable because a car would have a great deal of difficulty getting into, say, the stands.

Most vulnerable are street-facing entrances, and street malls, where cars generally share space with a great many people.

To mitigate this, we need to keep cars from sharing space with people - remove parking spaces directly in front of high traffic buildings, and build walking-only street malls (for example, Bourke Street Mall in Melbourne is completely elevated and with bollards, only certain vehicles like trams and armoured cars are allowed and only specially.) Build important buildings with spacious parks and plazas out the front.

As a bonus, this can be justified as tying into building more enjoyable public spaces, transforming a potential 'fear factor' into a 'liveable city factor'. For example, the State Library of Victoria with its lawns and steps and greek columns is basically immune to an attack like this, and it's by no means a product of a risk mitigation strategy.

### Hunt Down the Culprit

Bombs are... not easy. For one, they explode. And there's only so many people with the skills to become the Unabomber out there, and most of them are quite sane (and employed by the military.) Attackers capable of sophisticated bombing attacks are quite rare.

In any case after each individual threat is gone, there'll be plenty of evidence like phone records and witness testimony that will allow the police to hunt down the true culprit over the course of the coming months. Over the course of a few arrests and deaths, the threat of explosives will rapidly decline as the best-and-brightest of attackers get exposed and removed from the equation.

### Conclusion

Between these four factors, the risk of a serious attack can be quite efficiently mitigated (without panicking the electorate!) It's extremely unlikely an attacker gets a hold of explosives, but if they do, they can be stopped by remotely halting the car, and even if they don't get detected, their would-be targets are naturally unsuitable for dramatic attacks like this. And afterwards we keep arresting/shooting bomb-makers so the would-be attackers run out of bomb-making experts.

More likely than not, you'll end up facing a different threat altogether, once you've made the explosives attack completely infeasible (in fact, in the real world that's precisely why we're facing all these ramming-car attacks - our security agencies have basically killed the idea of sneaking around explosives stone dead.)

Answer (score 5):

**Same way we prevent regular car bombs:**

Most important buildings have large concrete "studs" in the ground between the building and the road.  This prevents cars with bombs from getting close.  There's obviously no way to put these everywhere, but then again, there's no way to prevent all car bombings.

You could potentially put sensors in self-driving cars to detect the scent of explosives, but I suspect that even this will be fool-able.  Maybe you could also add a discreet "panic button" for the driver to alert that their car has been hijacked.  Still, this won't stop terrorists from just driving non-autonomous cars like they currently do.

The bigger worry would be drone bombs. The can easily fly over barricades and deliver smaller, but still deadly, bombs to their target.  The solution here is guards with shotguns who will shoot down the drone (the White House already has these).  Shotgun-armed guards isn't a scale-able solution, so an automated system for detecting and shooting down drones is called for.  It would be difficult to prevent it form killing birds too, but hardly impossible.

Comment: The reason I am using car bombs is that drone bombs would be pretty pitifully sized, at least as of right now. An autonomous car or truck will be able to haul bombs on the order of tons; a drones a few kg at best.

Comment: @kingledion You're right, BUT a drone can get the bomb exactly where you want it, while a car can be stopped by obstructions.  If they're just trying to kill a bunch of people they can easily drive into a farmers market or whatever.  But if they're trying to kill anyone in particular, then a drone would be more effective.

Comment: This makes me wonder if you could use a drone bomb at long range to hit a bit of vital infrastructure, causing outsize damage with a small payload.

Comment: @Era well why not? See this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlO2gcs1YvM And here is something more real: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UAVs_in_the_U.S._military

Comment: Those studs in the ground are called *bollards*

Comment: @Era With enough of them, certainly.  Attack the big distribution transformers.  With the sort of effort a nation state could put behind it they could bring us to our knees without directly killing anyone.  I strongly suspect our response would be delivered by ICBM, though.

Comment: `It would be difficult to prevent it form killing birds too, but hardly impossible.` The main issue with false positive would not be the birds themselves, but that shooting in an urban area is likely to cause injuries or even death of bystanders. It is hard to argue against it when shooting against an actual threat (the responsability of the shooting lies with the attacker) but it would be very conflictive when it is just a system failure.

Comment: @SJuan76 There is actually a way to bypass having to use weaponry such as shotguns in order to take down drones. Creatively called the "Drone Gun", it essentially forces drones to land. The gun can even force the Drone to return to its starting point. According to the multiple websites such as the Washington Post, UAS Magazine and the company that made it (Drone Shield), the gun "could thwart drones carrying explosives intended to carry out a civilian or military attack"

Comment: @DevourerOfStars As I understand it, the Drone Gun would only work on drones the "gun" is familiar with.  If it was a custom-made drone using different commands the "gun" would have no way to override it's mission.  For now most people just use common commercial drones, but custom-made ones are hardly impossible, and would have to require kinetic solutions.

Answer (score 2):

### Automated checkpoints every `n` miles.

Just like the highway tolls barriers.

The number `n` of miles is an inverse function of the number of potential deflagration victims. Neighborhoods with government buildings would have a smaller `n`.

The checkpoints are equipped with ultra-fast [puffer machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puffer_machine) for smelling chemicals, X-ray gates for vehicles without humans aboard, or a full suite of biometric detectors to identify the passengers, including but not limited to cameras with face-recognition, voice recorders with timbre recognition, fingerprinting devices, and iris scanners.

> Attention! If explosives or other unauthorized substances are detected aboard, your vehicle may be removed or destroyed at any time by the law enforcement authority.

---

**[EDIT]**: actually an electric car does not burn fuel in the traditional sense. Provided that anything less than a hundred kilograms of explosive is just going to be insignificant in terms of threat, the obvious thing to do is to equip checkpoints with cameras and scales.

If the car is detected to be without passengers, and its weight between two consecutive checkpoints has changed, and it differs from the range declared by the car manufacturer, then the car is moved to a "secondary checkpoint zone", where the extra weight has to be justified, e.g. to verify whether it is due to luggage.

The verification of luggage can be done automatically using the puffer machines and X-ray scans. Remember that these analyses would be performed **only** on unoccupied vehicles. No harassment to citizens inside their car.

Comment: This doesn't seem feasible given the political climate in the US. Why would the people agree to such draconian car searching?

Comment: @kingledion to not die in bombing? Terrorism changes political climate, and changes it fast.

Comment: @kingledion for one, we already have exactly the same draconian searches in airports, and they are much slower and harassing than the one proposed here, and we did not need to agree: it befell on all of us. --- In contrast to current TSA searches, the automated checkpoints are 1) very quick (a matter of few seconds), 2) offer refill stations for your favorite sodas, 3) every time you pass by, you earn points that you can spend on iTunes  ;-)  4) you can track who among your friends has passed the largest number of checkpoints on foursquares  ;-) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Disallow autonomous vehicles without occupants.**

The current semiautonomous cars require occupants.  There are various ways to detect the position, size and weight of occupants.  Here is an example:

https://auto.howstuffworks.com/car-driving-safety/safety-regulatory-devices/ocs1.htm

> Let's take a look at one popular OCS made by Delphi. Inside the seat,
>   you will find a pressure sensor, a silicone-filled "bladder", and an
>   electronic control unit (ECU). When someone sits on the seat, the
>   pressure sensor signals the occupant's weight to the ECU. The ECU then
>   sends that data to the airbag, which has its own control unit. Based
>   on that information, the vehicle's computer turns the passenger airbag
>   on or off.
>
> The OCS doesn't just detect weight. It reads the passenger's seating
>   position and determines if they're wearing a seat belt. It also has a
>   seat belt tension sensor that allows the OCS to interpret the pressure
>   created when a child seat is fitted. In other words, the system is
>   designed to tell whether a child safety seat is occupying that seat or
>   whether you're just carrying some heavy object there.

A future system might use passive infrared, acoustics to hear heartbeats, and other methods to understand who was in the car and where.

So you can have a car that knows if it has an occupant.  But I can imagine people might like having their empty cars come to pick them up.  There is a group of people who would not like this at all: teamsters.  Driverless cars mean truckers and delivery drivers are out of work and their unions would oppose such cars on every level, including scare tactics like this scenario.  In fact if this were a detective thriller set in the near future (dare I hope?!) the union would be a fine culprit for an action like that described - pinning the blame on terrorists while cultivating a fear of driverless cars.

The way to prevent your scenario is to prevent empty cars.  Of course some group can kidnap the family of some poor schmo IRA style and compel him to go on a suicide run in his AMC Gremlin.  But that is less fun to think about.

Comment: "disallow" and what? Pressure sensors are [trivial to hack](https://xkcd.com/1559/), IR emmiters and ludspeakers are dirt cheap, and so on. Also, in the question nothing prevents car from being hacked, so software probably takes input from sensors and promptly ignores it, right? If not, it is rather trivial to physically hack most sensors on electric level, if you have to. Three easy ways to render your solution unusable. Only way to enforce this would have to be external, but then think about false positives.

Comment: I think the idea is a SF future where empty cars routinely go around and that fact is exploited by the terrorists.  How to avoid such a future?  But if you are going to have your terrorists be master hackers and engineers, and no-one will notice the fact a car has no driver, you could have the terrorists [make a remote control car](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtZ0iSrSuWY) and have that drive in the bomb.   They could do that now.

Comment: Why kidnap his family?  Kidnap him, strap him into the driver's seat but unconscious.

Comment: A smart terrorist would skip the Tesla and use an autonomous delivery truck (which will surely be available in near future)

Comment: Basically, if terrorists do the effort to steal the car and make the bomb, they'll surely take some effort to circumvent the sensors for "a human is present".

Comment: I am interested (hey, FBI, in theory, in theory!) in a bit different twist on it. Would it be possible to send a Tesla in a terrorist mission WITHOUT a bomb? Just hack and overload the battery.

Answer (score 1):

**Have Tesla help**

Obviously, Tesla must be getting some bad press for making cars that are being used as bombs. So have Tesla pair up with the government to stop it from happening.

**Some things you can do:**

You need to swipe your driver's license to start the car. If it isn't the owner's license, the car won't start.

The car won't drive without a rider. This would be easy to spoof, but its a start.

The car will not park illegally. It must pull into a valid parking space or a parking garage. This will help minimize casualties by keeping it out of crowded areas.

The car has a shield built into the shell that blocks certain RF frequencies.

The car can be tracked by the authorities. If the cops know the car was stolen, they can find it.

The car has internal cameras. This will identify if there are people in the car and will let the cops see if the car is filled with explosives.

The cops can change the car's destination. They can drive it out of the area when they notice the threat.

The car only responds to voice commands by its owner. The car can use voice recognition and analysis.

The car only responds to the fingerprint of the driver. The driver has to scan a fingerprint to change direction or to stop the car.

The car sends the police pictures. If the car is left in park for a long time, the car will use image recognition with its internal camera to check for explosives and send the cops an alert if any are found.

The car has shielding to stop the bombs. If this becomes a massive problem, the cars can be armored to withstand explosions.

The car will not speed or disobey traffic rules. This is a given, but rigged cars will take longer to get where they are going.

On top of these, the car can have a trusted boot system so it won't start if the operating system has been tampered with. This is a good idea regardless of the bomb problem because you don't want hackers to program someone's car to drive off a cliff next time they go for a ride.

Answer (score 0):

First, I love the situation. It's an intriguing look at possible negative aspects of autonomous vehicles. I am assuming that except for self driving cars your technology is mostly the same as modern technology.  I have a few ideas.

**Why Don't the Good Guys Hack the Tesla Model X-2?**

This isn't an illogical approach. It is possible to remotely [hack and control a modern Tesla](https://www.cnbc.com/2016/09/20/chinese-company-hacks-tesla-car-remotely.html). Though, the obvious question is what to do once you have the car hacked. Do you drive to a secure location? However, that risks going past civilians the and potential of more deaths. Maybe (I don't know the geography of the area so I don't know if there is a lake nearby or anything) in a really dramatic scene the car is driven into a lake and explodes. I think something like that happened in a Jack Ryan movie, but that didn't involve hacking, so this is definitely cooler.

**Why Don't the Good Guys Find the Bad Guys?**

There a few things I can't work based on how your is set up, but is it feasible that the good guys find the bad guys and take them out seconds before the explode command?

**Why Don't the Good Buys Set Up Big Trucks to Stop the Car?**

This idea is based on how large trucks were used at New Year's Eve in New York to stop terrorist from driving through the crowds. This might not work as planned because the car would still go off, but you could gave the all important government building.

**Why Don't The Good Guys Find the Car and Disconnect the Bomb?**

Again, I don't know the entire situation so I don't know if it would work for you to send a team to find the car and disconnect the bomb before the bomb.

That is all I could think of.